# CakePHP 3: Nested SQL functions in a query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

After years of using CakePHP 2, I've migrated to CakePHP 3 a week ago. The new ORM is awesome, but it makes me stumble upon some basic things, which used to work back then and behave differently in the new version.

How am I supposed to build this query on the `UsersTable` in Cake's orgy of `find()`, `where()` and `query()` chain methods?

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = "ex@ample.com" AND `password`= SHA1(MD5(CONCAT("somePassword", `salt`)))
```

I'll go without posting my trials of achieving this, I tried pretty much about adding expressions, conditions etc. Now I'm curious about how it really should be done.

**Edit**: This question is *not* about authentication, it is much more about how to perform such queries in CakePHP 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, nested functions can be created by simply nesting function expressions.

```
use Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression;
use Cake\Database\Expression\Cake\ORM\Query;
```

```
$email = 'foo@bar.baz';
$password = 'foo';
$salt = 'bar';

$Users = TableRegistry::get('Users');

$query = $Users
    ->find()
    ->where(function(QueryExpression $exp, Query $query) use ($email, $password, $salt) {
        return
            $exp->and_([
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => $query->func()->SHA1([
                    $query->func()->MD5([
                        $query->func()->CONCAT([
                            $password,
                            'salt' => 'identifier'
                        ])
                    ])
                ])
            ]);
    });
```

or, which might be considered a little more simple

```
$functionsBuilder = $Users->query()->func();

$query = $Users
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $functionsBuilder->SHA1([
            $functionsBuilder->MD5([
                $functionsBuilder->CONCAT([
                    $password,
                    'salt' => 'identifier'
                ])
            ])
        ])
    ]);
```

It should be noted that this is just an example for nesting, when doing authentication, use authentication handlers and proper password hashers as mentioned by @AlexStallen

See also **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL functions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**

Comment: This way of nesting wasn't clear to me after I read the docs first. But still - we have to know `salt` first. So it is still not the solution of my question. Using pure SQL, you need only ONE query (as I pointed out in my question). It must be somehow possible in Cake too...

Comment: @BarthZalewski My bad, I've overlooked that `salt` is a column reference... I'll update my answer.

Comment: @BarthZalewski Answer updated, showing the use of the `literal` option.

Comment: That's it. You managed to give me a fishing pole rather than a fish - means: you taught me something important about Cake's ORM: how to use SQL functions, how to nest them and how to use literals. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You should really read this: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html and then you can do something like:

```
$hasher = $this->passwordHasher();
$hashedPassword = $user->get($fields['password']); //password from the database
      if (!$hasher->check('password_given_by_the_user', $hashedPassword)) {
            return false;
      }
//password is ok if we reach this point
```

Nesting SQL: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

```
$this->Model->find()
    ->where([$conditions])
    ->where([$more_conditions]);
```

Comment: Ok, looks better now. I'll give it a try. Thank you a lot for your efforts.